# Windows 10 GPO QoS by URL not applying

Tags: networking, windows-10, qos

I've created a GPO with QoS settings and I can confirm the PC is domain joined.

```
Name           : Test
Owner          : Group Policy (Machine)
NetworkProfile : Domain
Precedence     : 0
JobObject      :
URI            : http://sub-domain.domain.com:443/
URIRecursive   : True
DSCPValue      : 12
```

I also have the registry modification

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\QoS 
REG_DWORD "Do not use NLA" set to 1
```

And selected `Applications' DSCP Marking Request` to `Allowed`

One additional info is that, I'm not typing `http://sub-domain.domain.com:443/` but `https://sub-domain.domain.com/` in the GPO Editor. Don't know if that is expected.

If I look at the packet capture I don't get any change to DSCP. If I select "All aplications" I do get DSCP correct and working as expected.